# Magento 2.1.6 Conflicting components dependencies

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, conflict, magento2.1.6

with a fresh install of Magento 2.1.6, I'm trying to install any compatible extension, and I always get this message below:

> Check Component Dependency
>   We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail
>
> For additional assistance, see component dependency help.

with no further explanation letting me know what's the problem

everything else seems to be working fine "Cron jobs", I tried everything on the web

- expanded my memory.
- managed users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may see `"require-dev"` tag in composer.json file.

Run composer install or update with `--no-dev` flag. This will not install developer dependency packages.

```
composer install --no-dev
```

OR

```
composer update --no-dev
```

Comment: exactly what i did, and it solved everything, thank you

Comment: could you kindly help me ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/222817/57334

Answer (score 4):

Removing the following from composer.json worked for me also to get past this issue.

```
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
```

Would be really interesting to know why removing this worked?

Comment: Not working : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/222817/57334

Answer (score 1):

After two days trying different things, also worked for me the following:

Removing the following from composer.json worked for me also to get past this issue.

},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me, open this file on your module:

```
app/code/NEWMODULE/NAME/etc/module.xml
```

Then check the dependencies, and check if you have **all dependencies** modules installed and enable.

You can check the modules enabled using this command:

```
php -f bin/magento module:status
```

Comment: i solved it already by removing the Require dev tag from the composer.json actually

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes removing below lines from composer.json worked for me as well

```
    },
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
```

Thank you for the solution !!

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in because the above solutions didn't work for my instance.  In the Magento root directory, I changed the memory_limit in **.htaccess** and **.user.ini** to **2G** (from 756M) and I was able to proceed.