# Magento2 Upgrade Readiness Check Error - Check Cron & Check Component dependency

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, readiness-check

unable to upgrade Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 on CentOS, Apache2, php7.2, webuzo control panel

- currently in developer mode
- file permissions as https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html#Production-file-system-ownership-for-private-hosting-two-users-%3E
- /var/.htaccess permission tried with 666 also, but nothing happening.
- database also connected.

[image: Upgrade Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !!

1. Cron error - was due to crons not setup properly, check for php memory in

> php.ini
>
> magento root/.htaccess
>
> magento root/user.ini

, check the cron setup in your webcontrol panel or through Terminal https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

2. Dependency Error - Resolved by removing lines from composer.json as per post https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/288006/77564

>

```
 },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
```